# Removing UID from breadcrumbs in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I made breadcums automatically on CodeIgniter but, on the user profile editing view, my uuid is shown as uri->segment. I think It will look cleaner without the uuid. How can I skip, delete or hide it?

MY url

http://localhost/myproject/user/edit/0004055ac42e42bcb57183646e84ff05

Breadcumbs with helper

> HOME > User > edit > 0004055ac42e42bcb57183646e84ff05

I expect it

> HOME > User > edit

Helper breadcumbs:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('generateBreadcrumb')){
function generateBreadcrumb(){
  $ci = &get_instance();

  $i=1;
  $uri = $ci->uri->segment($i);
  $link = '
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
     <li><a href="'.site_url().'"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>';

  while($uri != ''){
    $prep_link = '';
  for($j=1; $j<=$i;$j++){
    $prep_link .= $ci->uri->segment($j).'/';
  }

  if($ci->uri->segment($i+1) == ''){
    $link.='<li class="active"><a href="'.site_url($prep_link).'">';
    $link.=$ci->uri->segment($i).'</a></li> ';
  }else{
    $link.='<li><a href="'.site_url($prep_link).'">';
    $link.=$ci->uri->segment($i).'</a><span class="divider"></span></li> ';
  }

  $i++;
  $uri = $ci->uri->segment($i);
  }
    $link .= '</ol>';
    return $link;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: why can't u use $this->router->fetch_class(); for fetching your controller name and $this->router->fetch_method(); for your method name to generate your breadcrumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this only happen after "**User > edit**"?  If so, how about adding a conditional that looks for that sequence and ignores the segment if found?

I'd like to test this but I don't have a playground ready. See if this works for you:

```
if ( $i>1 && $ci->uri->segment($i) == 'edit' && $ci->uri->segment($i-1) == 'User' ) {
    //just ignore this
} else {
  if($ci->uri->segment($i+1) == ''){
    $link.='<li class="active"><a href="'.site_url($prep_link).'">';
    $link.=$ci->uri->segment($i).'</a></li> ';
  }else{
    $link.='<li><a href="'.site_url($prep_link).'">';
    $link.=$ci->uri->segment($i).'</a><span class="divider"></span></li> ';
  }
}
```

Another solution would be to check if `strlen($ci->uri->segment($i))` equals 32.  Of course this will only work if you expect uuid to always be 32 characters and no other URI segment to be that long.

Comment: thanks @zJorge I use your answer because it is very simple to use my previous helper. solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this.its works only if you want to add your controller and method name in breadcrumb

```
 $c=$this->router->fetch_class();;
 $m=$this->router->fetch_method();
 $link="";
 $link.='<li><a href="'.site_url().'"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>';

 if($m!='index')
 {
  $link.='<li><a href="'.site_url($c).'">$c</li>
 <li><a class="active" href="'.site_url($m).'">$m</li>';
 }
 else
 {
 $link.='<li><a class="active" href="'.site_url($c).'">$c</li>';
 }
```

Comment: thanks @Saravana Dev for the reply, already try to script that you give, but not as I expected so I am trying to edit from the answers zJorge